# Rails Admin help

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git, rubygems, heroku

I was pushing to heroku and everything seemed to be going fine until i went to the url. I get this error at the url:

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

Here is whats in my logs when i do `heroku logs`

```
2011-08-04T11:15:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-08-04T11:15:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-08-04T11:15:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-04T11:15:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `new'
2011-08-04T11:15:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2011-08-04T11:15:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-08-04T11:15:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2011-08-04T11:15:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2011-08-04T11:15:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-08-04T11:24:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-08-04T11:24:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-08-04T11:24:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 39394 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `rescue in establish_connection': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (RuntimeError)
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:68:in `establish_connection'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:67:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/h

2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `new'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `map'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'

11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-08-04T11:24:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-08-04T11:35:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-08-04T11:35:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-08-04T11:35:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 19656 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `rescue in establish_connection': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (RuntimeError)
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:68:in `establish_connection'

0:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:67:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `new'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `map'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby

2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-08-04T11:35:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
thomas@thomas-laptop:~/Developer/superrails$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your postgres gem to your Gemfile

your error:

> Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (RuntimeError)

Answer (score 0):

The cause is written on the log: you should add this

```
gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'
```

to your `Gemfile`, then run a `bundle install` and then commit and push to heroku these two resources:

- Gemfile
- Gemfile.lock